# Won't load CSS WordPress Site

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, iis

I'm working on a WordPress based website, the webpage loads fine but the CSS and JavaScript won't load in. Here's a screenshot from FireBug:

[image: screengrab]

I have access to the server. It's a Windows server running IIS7. This is an issue that's just started, it wasn't like this last night and nothing was changed by me (or anyone else in the company as far as I know).

As you see I'm getting the error:
"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

I am really stuck on fixing this, can anyone help out?

Comment: The [wordpress support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/forum/how-to-and-troubleshooting) might be a better place for such kind of questions.

Comment: http://forums.iis.net/t/1159252.aspx
see this , maybe it will help you..

Comment: Do you frequently run PHP on IIS? Have you tried bouncing the server?

Comment: I use Linux servers normally and am a mac user, only an intern too do havn't much experience at all! What's bouncing? If it's restarting I tried that.

Comment: Have you checked that a redirection script isn't getting in the way?

Comment: Someone else managed to fix it, it was a 'duplicate mime type' or something

Comment: Wrong file permissions may be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an internal server error it may be with your hosting provider there may be a problem with the hosting service if the files are all there.